# В чем причина ошибки "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

Пытаюсь решить задачу, но ничего не получается. Я искал информацию об ошибке, но не нашел ответа. Прошу помочь.

Текст задачи, если интересно:

> Дана непустая строка и целое число `n`. Вернуть новую строку, в которой символ
>   на `n`'ой позиции будет удалён. Значение `n` - валидная позиция
>   символа в оригинальной строке (`n` находится в промежутке
>   `[0;str.length - 1]`.

```
public class Five{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        missingChar mschar = new missingChar("abcdefghigklmnopqrstuwxyz", 5);
        System.out.println(mschar);
    }


    public String missingChar(String word, int n){
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            if(word[i] == n){
                for(int j = i; j < word.length - 1; j++){
                    word[j] = word[j+1];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот, кстати, сам текст ошибки:

```
Five.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            missingChar mschar = new missingChar("abcdefghigklmnopqrstuwxyz", 5);
            ^
```

Comment: Ну как бы из кода видно, что нужно почитать хотя бы об основах языка, чтобы не путать классы и методы.

Comment: Решите за меня, называется, здесь русское сообщество и англ. не уместен, переведите на русский или перенесите вопрос, на англ. сообщество.

Comment: спасибо большое. Учту замечания по поводу английского)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, правильный ответ уже был дан в комментариях. Нужно изучить основы языка. И когда основы будут изучены, вы увидите, что существуют гораздо более удобные способы решения этой задачи, чем решение через циклы.

С помощью обычного цикла задача решается так:

```
public static String missingChar1(String word, int n){
    String res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++){
        if (i < n) {
            res += word.charAt(i);
        } else {
            res += word.charAt(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Но в Java есть встроенный класс `StringBuilder`, который, помимо прочих удобных методов, позволяет удалять символы из строки непосредственно. Метод `delete(a, b)` удаляет из строки все символы с индексами от `a` до `b`, включая `a`, но не включая `b`. Зная это, можно упростить решение до вот такого вида:

```
public static String missingChar2(String word, int n){
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(word);
    res.delete(n, n + 1);
    return res.toString();
}
```

Однако, можно привести еще более короткое решение, воспользовавшись стандартным методом `substring()` класса `String`. Просто взять кусок строки до заданного символа и "склеить" (конкантенировать) его с куском строки после этого символа.

```
public static String missingChar3(String word, int n){
    return word.substring(0, n) + word.substring(n + 1);
}
```

Желаю вам успехов в изучении красивого и элегантного языка **Java**!

Comment: все круто и примеры хорошие, но ответ не отвечает , собственно, на вопрос (изучить основы, это, мягко говоря, не самая очевидная причина)

Comment: "Изучить основы" не только не самая очевидная причина, а вообще не причина уже потому, что отвечает на вопрос "Что делать?", а не "В чем причина?". И мой ответ не отвечает и не может ответить уже потому, что приведенный ТС код является ошибочным от начала и до конца. О чем, собственно, и сказал (другими словами) Эникейщий в своем комментарии. Я разместила здесь эти примеры не для ответа, а для того чтобы внести дополнительную мотивацию топикстартеру в изучении языка. Согласитесь, что в комментариях это было бы сделать затруднительно.

Comment: @AliceMagic от души благодарю вас за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Ты написал метод, а не класс. Метод - это тоже самое, что и функция. Он выполняет какое-либо действие, и в зависимости от типа метода, может либо вернуть значение, либо нет. Так же ты создал по видимому экземпляр метода(такого не бывает!). Экземпляры бывают только класса!

Нет ничего страшного, как только пройдешь раздел классы, можешь смело реализовывать!

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ)